# How do I remove this white background from my inline-block element

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following html/css code:

### HTML

```
<div id="statusSteps">
    <span class="step complete">step 1</span>
    <span class="step complete">step 2</span>
    <span class="step complete">step 3</span>
    <span class="step">step 4</span>
    <span class="step">step 5</span>
</div>​
```

### CSS

```
#statusSteps {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.step {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.step:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.complete {
    background-color: LightGray;
}​
```

I created a JSFiddle to play around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/wMShU/

In the browsers I tried (Firefox, IE9, and Chrome) there is a white area on the left side of step 1 and step 2.

Does anyone know a nice clean way to have those steps with the gray background fill the whole area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution by Miljan Puzović works, but then you may remove `display: inline-block` entirely (floated elements are all implicitly `display: block`).

The cause of your issue is that `inline-block` elements are influenced by whitespace on the markup. If you remove the whitespace between the `<span>` tags (which *will* make your code look ugly), the white margin will go away.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wMShU/2/).

Comment: Wow, never mind my previous comment (deleted, oops too late).  I tested it too, and you are right: It certainly does seem to override the display to implicitly to "block".  But is this just some artifact?    It's not obvious from the specifications. Hrm...

Comment: I can't cite any source, but I learnt that years ago... Your now-deleted comment made me think about it, I will do some research to find the documentation.

Comment: Well, it's not the specs, but this AFAIK is reputable: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/displaypositionfloat . Facinating.  I wish I could +1 your answer one more time!

Comment: Perfect answer.  I am actually going to switch to using the the float left so I don't have the problem with the whitespace in the code, but I think this answers what I was wondering the most.

Answer (score 4):

Add `float: left;` to `.step` class. I've added `float: left` and edited your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wMShU/1/

Comment: I think @bfavaretto's answer was what I thought I wanted (an explanation of what was going on and how to fix it using my existing css), but looking at the options I'm going to just use the float as you suggest here.  Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: I'm glad that I helped :) English is not my native language and i've learned English by myself, so it's a little harder for me to explain what i'm thinking :)